# Gowers' proof of Szemerdi's theorem

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, reference-request, fourier-analysis

Are there any good books or other resources (expository notes) which explains Gowers' proof of Szemerdi's theorem in detail?

Comment: Gowers's papers on the topic are characteristically very clear. They can be found at https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~wtg10/papers.html

Answer (score 2):

I learned of it through Tao and Vu's book [Additive Combinatorics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521136563), but this is not an easy read (on the other hand, it's not an easy proof).